# Is there any way to host a blockchain which is implemented from scratch using python?

Tags: python, cloud, blockchain, flask-restful

I have recently created a blockchain from scratch using python language. Its backend is implemented using flask.I need to host several nodes in the blockchain in a cloud server.Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking exactly, but the most obvious answer is that you can pay a cloud provider for space/computational power and host your code there.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain specifics: code, inputs, expected vs actual outputs, errors, etc. Currently this is off-topic as written, as it's broad and opinion-based (and arguably a hosting recommendation question). I removed `azure` from your tags, as this question has nothing to do with Azure, as written. (to be honest, it has nothing to do with `python` or `flask-restful` either, currently, as there's no code or any other specifics).